# python loc and conditions similar to SQL

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So in SQL I can treat two conditions as "one" instead of two in the where statement

```
Where x=2 and (y>2 and z =10)
```

My understanding that within python .loc is the approximate translation, I'm wondering how I can replicate this behavior.

```
scout.loc[scout['nflId'].isin(OLs.nflId) 
                     & (~scout['gameId'].isin(brokenplays.gameId))
                     & (~scout['playId'].isin(brokenplays.playId))]
```

I need gameId and playId to function as a singular condition as neither gameId or playId is distinct enough to function as a PK, but together they can function as a PK.

I've tried throwing different (), [], and even including them together in the scout[''] part and don't get the data I want or I get error statement.

Comment: Why are you using `&` instead of `and`?

Comment: @JohnGordon That is because in numpy and pandas & operator is used to do element wise computation on whole vectors where as with `and` you cannot do that.

Comment: `a and (b and c)` is equivalent to `a and b and c`. It seems from your question that you want 3 things to be true at the same time, so using `&` twice should be fine. Perhaps you do not need the two `~` squiggles? Currently you are retrieving each scout for which it is true that its `nflId` value appears in the iterable  `OLS.nflId`; AND its `gameId` does NOT appear in the iterable `brokenplays.gameId`; AND its `playId` does NOT appear in the iterable `brokenplays.playId`.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example of dataframe on which you want to evaluate the condition and desired output.

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry should have been more clear. The first code line is SQL and this second code line is from pythons. Hopefully this clear it up for for you.

Comment: As @Chrysophylaxs said, `a and b and c` is exactly the same as `a and (b and c)`.  I don't know what you are actually asking here.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs I'm using the ~ because my understanding of python is when I use it within context of isin it becomes similar to not in it. 

To provide more context here scout is a dataframe that contains NFL games and plays. Scout's key variables are gameId, playId, and nflId. As such there are multiple 'dupes' of gameId and playId, but only 1 instance of all 3 together. What I'm trying to do is narrow to certain players (done by the nflId) and certain plays. Scout contains all the plays while brokenplays only contains some. I want all the plays that are in scout and not in brokenplays.